# Execute JS before CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="example.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form class="search">
    <div class="search_box">
         <input type="text" name="q" id="search_text" placeholder="Search..." />
             <ul id="search_results" class="results" >
                 <li><a href="">Search Result #1<br /><span>Description...</span></a></li>
                 <li><a href="">Search Result #2<br /><span>Description...</span></a></li>
             </ul>
    </div>
</form>
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on('click', '#search_results li',function(i) {
              i.preventDefault();
              console.log('clicked');
          });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

and the css looks like this:

```
.search .search_box input:focus +  .results { visibility: visible }

.search .search_box .results {
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

If the css is not included the document works as expected and prints "clicked" when clicking on one of the anchor tags, but not when including the css.

So I suspect the item is hidden before the javascript is executed. I really like the css solution more than having hide and toggle javascript statements.

Is there a method to fix this?

Comment: If the elements are hidden, how are you clicking on them? What is your desired outcome here?

Comment: Huh? How are you supposed to click something that's hidden? If you want to click them, don't hide them. You can attach a click handler to a hidden element, but obviously it won't do anything until you make that element visible. What are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: when you make the input box "active" the elements are no longer hidden. I want to then register a onclick event for one of the list items

Comment: please see this line `.search .search_box input:focus +  .results { visibility: visible }`

Comment: Is it not that when you click the list items the search box no longer has focus and so the second line of CSS that sets `.results`'s visibility to `hidden` applies - thus making them invisible an unable to be clicked?

Comment: Well, yeah, your problem is that you lose focus before the click event. `mousedown` might work better.

Comment: @Joshua Brodie I would assume so, and that's why I am asking how this would be done

Comment: Let's try to find out, what you want. You have a search textfield and search results, which appear, when the search textfield is focussed. When you click on the search results, you think, the css blur event of the searh input is executed first and so the search results are hidden by css before the JS can access them? IS this right?

Comment: Is changing the CSS not an option?

Comment: @HerrSeker Yes,and for crush yes it is an option

Comment: @Chaosekie In that case, I think epascarello has the best solution to your problem below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a hover state to keep the items visible.

```
.search .search_box input +  .results:hover,
.search .search_box input:focus +  .results { visibility: visible }

.search .search_box .results {
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

Working fiddle for the downvoters: http://jsfiddle.net/cEP95/

Comment: Won't this reveal the items when hovering them and the input isn't focused?

Comment: It seems that the hover event doesn't fire when the element's visibility is hidden, so [this does in fact work](http://jsfiddle.net/h9x84/).

Comment: If changing the CSS is an option, this is probably the best solution.

Comment: This does the same thing as my original example, I can't get it to log "clicked"

Comment: @Chaosekie What browser, works fine in my fiddle with Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: @epascarello Yeah seems it was a chrome issue, works perfectly after a browser restart

Answer (score 6):

Change `click()` to `mousedown()`. The click event includes a mouse up to register, and by that time the focus has been lost.

```
$(document).on('mousedown', '#search_results li', function (i) {
    i.preventDefault();
    console.log('clicked');
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/5d3bs/)**

Comment: So this does seem to solve the problem of getting the event to register, but I was under the impression that `i.preventDefault();` will cause the anchor tag to not function as a link?

Comment: @Chaosekie It will prevent the link's default action. He just put it there because you had it in your code above. It won't follow the `href` attribute (which is the default action). You can still click it and the event will fire.

Comment: To cancel the link you can add a `$('#search_results a').click(function(e){e.preventDefault()})`. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/9vLhs/

Comment: Yeah that is what I thought, I didn't want the link to be followed but I see this is because I was selecting the list item and not the anchor

Comment: @Chaosekie Ah. I overlooked that too. Good catch.

Comment: @j08691 I don't think you saved that fiddle, if I change it to an anchor tag such as `$('#search_results a')` for some reason the link is still followed?

Comment: @j08691 nevermind I see what you meant with the example.

Comment: This works except that the search_results isn't hidden after clicking on one of them

Comment: In the click suppression code you could add `$('.search .search_box input:focus').blur();`. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/38MRF/

Answer (score 3):

Try using `opacity:0` and `opacity:1` instead of `visibility:hidden` and `visibility:visible` respectively.

This is because the order of events when you click is:

- Blur the previous element - this causes `:hover` to no longer apply
- Click on the new element... but it's hidden now!

Comment: Great Solution! But wouldn't this cause any items that follow to be far below or right of the text box?

Comment: @Chaosekie `visibility` does the same thing. If you want to remove them from the flow of the page, you need to use `display: none`.

Comment: @crush Sorry about that, I originally had display:none but put in visibility while trying to find a solution

Answer (score -2):

In response to "Execute JS before CSS", the only road consists to load the css stylesheet once the dom is ready.
So, you can try something like:

**Somewhere in your  section:**

```
<style type="text/css">
body { display: none }
</style>
```

**JS:**

```
 $(function() {
     $('head').append('<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="example.css" />');
 });
```

**In the css:**

```
body { display: block }
```

Comment: Missing the point... Pay attention to what part of the CSS makes the element shown/hidden.